# g++ compiler issue with aligned_storage - Is this a compiler bug?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, c++14, generic-programming

I copied a program below from this [link](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/type_traits/aligned_storage/)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

struct A {  // non-POD type
  int avg;
  A (int a, int b) : avg((a+b)/2) {}
};

typedef std::aligned_storage<sizeof(A),alignof(A)>::type A_pod;

int main() {
  A_pod a,b;
  new (&a) A (10,20);
  b=a;
  std::cout << reinterpret_cast<A&>(b).avg << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

I ran gdb on this code to understand the size of various constituents and the results are as below:

```
(gdb) b 18
Breakpoint 1 at 0x96d: /home/ripunjay/study/bitbucket/study/cpp/aligned_storage.cpp:18. (3 locations)
(gdb) r
Starting program: /home/ripunjay/study/bitbucket/study/cpp/aligned_storage 

Breakpoint 1, _GLOBAL__sub_I_main () at aligned_storage.cpp:18
18  }
(gdb) ptype a
type = const union {
    int i[2];
    double d;
}
(gdb) ptype A_pod
type = union std::aligned_storage<4, 4>::type {
    unsigned char __data[4];
    struct {
        <no data fields>
    } __align;
}
(gdb) ptype A_
No symbol "A_" in current context.
(gdb) ptype A
type = struct A {
    int avg;
  public:
    A(int, int);
}
(gdb) p sizeof(A)
$1 = 4
(gdb) p sizeof(a)
$2 = 8
(gdb) p sizeof(b)
$3 = 8

(gdb) ptype A
type = struct A {
    int avg;
  public:
    A(int, int);
}
```

Later on to see a normal constructor call I added a single line in main() to construct an object c as follows -

```
int main() {
  A_pod a,b;
  A c(10,20);
  new (&a) A (10,20);
  b=a;
  std::cout << reinterpret_cast<A&>(b).avg << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

This caused the sizes and even type definitions for a and b to change. It was quite surprising that even if this newly added line is commented out the compiler has different behaviour.

```
(gdb) r
Starting program: /home/ripunjay/study/bitbucket/study/cpp/aligned_storage 
15

Breakpoint 1, main () at aligned_storage.cpp:18
18    return 0;
(gdb) ptype a
type = union std::aligned_storage<4, 4>::type {
    unsigned char __data[4];
    struct {
        <no data fields>
    } __align;
}
(gdb) ptype b
type = union std::aligned_storage<4, 4>::type {
    unsigned char __data[4];
    struct {
        <no data fields>
    } __align;
}
(gdb) ptype A_pod
type = union std::aligned_storage<4, 4>::type {
    unsigned char __data[4];
    struct {
        <no data fields>
    } __align;
}


g++ --version 
g++ (Ubuntu 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04) 7.5.0 Copyright (C) 2017 Free Software Foundation, Inc. This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

Comment: `b` is uninitialised so your program has undefined behaviour

Comment: `reinterpret_cast<A&>(b).avg` exhibits undefined behavior, by way of accessing an object (of type `A`) before its lifetime has started.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik - I am not looking at the output of cout at all - I am rather looking at gdb and sizeof. Please let me know how that is controlled by uninitialized b. Also please look at the definition of a and b in both cases.

Answer (score 1):

By doing this `std::cout << reinterpret_cast<A&>(b).avg << std::endl;` your program exhibits undefined behavior. Why? You use uninitalized value.

What does that imply? That compiler is allowed to do anything. And by anything I mean literally anything, including blowing up your computer - it is allowed by the standard. And so seeing change in type sizes/padding/alignment and so on in gdb is no wonder. Compiler is allowed to do so since you entered the realm of undefiend bahaviour.

IMHO, but there's no easy way to be sure, due to UB size/alignment of your `class A` changed. Since it changed the internals of the `std::aligned_storage` changed with it (because aligned storage internals can have very different internal representations for different size/alignment pairs).